# The parts of this model are not showing in game engine nor do they have shading

Tags: game-engine

I'm new to the Blender game engine and I don't know what to do with this model glitch. Certain parts of the model aren't showing and there is no shading. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: its hard to tell since we don't know how it's supposed to look, but try recalculating normals and changing the viewport from solid to textured

Comment: try chaining to textured shading. You are in solid.

Comment: that did not work at all i guess this model is not fer the bge

Answer (score 1):

For the shading problem: the viewport is currently in shaded mode
[image]
If the textures still aren't showing, bear in mind that only image textures are supported.

For parts of the model not showing, it is likely that the normals are inverted or that you are using single planes. In computer graphics, most faces have only one side, and if you look from the other side they will be transparent. To fix this you can:
 - Flip the normal to face the correct way (edit mode -> select face -> ctrl+N)
 - Disable backface culling

Viewing the normals using one of the following options is reccomended:
[image]
As should be evident, the selected faces have their normals flipped and are thus not visible from where the camera is.

Comment: Also from what I remember the BGE only likes a few image file formats for textures like jpeg and TGA i think